# Unzip gives me file path for filename

Tags: unzip, esri

When I run `unzip dir.zip` and `ls -l` the result,

I got:

- `widgets\Draw\setting\nls\et\strings.js`

I expect:

- `widgets`

The zip is generated on windows with nodejs.

Thanks